# UiViewControllers are not loaded from tab bar item in swift after using objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, swift3, bridging-header

I am writing an application in swift 3 where I have several views connected by segues for different tab bar item.I imported a rotary wheel project from Github using bridging header and dropped all the objective c files inn my project. In the Appdelegate.swift file I converted the codes in Appdelegate.m file and paste it there

```
var window: UIWindow?
    var viewController: SMViewController!



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        self.window! = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.viewController = SMViewController(nibName: "SMViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.window!.rootViewController = self.viewController

        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true


    }
```

The wheel image is loaded in the SMViewController.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    SMWheelControl *wheel = [[SMWheelControl alloc] initWithFrame:self.wheelContainer.bounds];

    [wheel addTarget:self action:@selector(wheelDidChangeValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [wheel insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"WheelBackground"]] atIndex:0];
    wheel.delegate = self;
    wheel.dataSource = self;
    [wheel reloadData];

    [self.wheelContainer addSubview:wheel];

    self.wheel = wheel;

}
```

I imported SMViewController.xib file in the project. And also in the Main.Storyboard file I set the viewcontroller as SMViewController from the identity inspector. When my app launches, the wheel from the git project is showing fine after the launch screen but all my other views are not showing. I dont know why this is happening. Any help is highly appreciated.

[image: Please see the first screenshot where I used storyboard for the tab bar controllers] [image: And this is the app not showing my tab bars or other views]

Comment: I see that you make the `SMViewController` the root controller for your app, but where does the tab bar come into play?

Comment: I used storyboard and segues to connects the tab bar items with the view controller  as you can see from the screenshots in my edited answer. Where should i change to make this work?

Comment: I think you want your root view controller to be loaded as the initial controller from your storyboard instead of making it a `SMViewController` in app delegate code.

Comment: WHat will be the code for this ?

Comment: Set the correct initial view controller in your storyboard (if it isn't set already) and remove the code you added in the app delegate to make the wheel root.  Load the `SMViewController` in the tab where you want it to appear.

Comment: I removed Appdelegate code.Added this line in -(void) viewDidLoad SMViewController *vc = [[SMViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SMViewController" bundle:nil].Now its a black screen in my tab bar controller but the login screen is showing

Answer (score 0):

I was running right. I don't know exactly meaning of "other views",Is it write in your SMViewController ? Can you upload your code in GitHub , I could help you more.

---

1. set your ViewController's Nav "is Initial View Controller"
2. set your ViewController's Class
3. remove code you added in "AppDelegate.swift"

Then you will see the VC you want, I guess.

[image: set your nav Controller]

[image: set your viewController]

Comment: Please see my edited question.I added two screenshots of my projects.